# How can I select a certain value based on 2(or more) other values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to find out how to select a certain value based on multiple other values in the same tuple of a dataframe.  The data looks like this(copied from the current dataframe)

```
    DealID      PropId LoanId   ServicerId    ServicerPropId
0   BAC98765      15   000015    30220144       010-002-001
1   BAC98765      16   000016    30220092       010-003-001
2   BAC98765      45   000045    30220155       010-045-001
3   BAC98765      48   000048    30220157       010-048-001
```

In SQL terms what I would like to accomplish is this:

```
Select ServicerPropId from dataframe
 where DealID = 'BAC98765' and ServicerId = '30220144'
```

I've tried a few different ways to slice the data, but can't seem to figure out how to get multiple selection criteria to work and return only 1 value into a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
columns = ['DealID', 'PropId', 'LoanId', 'ServicerId', 'ServicerPropId']

d = [('A', [ 'BAC98765', '15', '000015', '30220144', '010-002-001']),
     ('B', [ 'BAC98765', '16', '000016', '30220092', '010-003-001']),
     ('C', [ 'BAC98765', '45', '000045', '30220155', '010-045-001']),
     ('D', [ 'BAC98765', '48', '000048', '30220157', '010-048-001']),]

D =  pandas.DataFrame.from_items(d, orient='index', columns=columns)

criterion1 = D['DealID'].map(lambda x: x == 'BAC98765' )
criterion2 = D['ServicerId'].map(lambda x: x == '30220144')

res = D[criterion1 & criterion2]['ServicerPropId']
```

Using the `map` lets you put in any condition you want, in this case you can do this more simply (as pointed out in the comments by DSM)

```
res = D[(D['DealID'] == "BAC98765") & (D["ServicerId"] == "30220144")]['ServicerPropId']
```

Which gives

```
In [35]: print res
A    010-002-001
Name: ServicerPropId

In [36]: type(res)
Out[36]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

[(doc)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: I don't think the maps are necessary; `D[(D['DealID'] == "BAC98765") & (D["ServicerId"] == "30220144")]` should work.

Comment: That worked just fine - in my particular case no mapping is necessary but the last line of code you gave is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.